# Why is that Strange Behaviour with SETOF in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following Code Snippets{ CODE#1 , CODE#2, CODE #3 } In my Database.

**CODE #1** : Create Statement of a Table "Class_Type" which is like a "ENUM in JAVA".

It Contains some data as { "class-A", 'class-B", "sports-A", "RED", "BLUE",.....}

Now i am trying to fetch these values using a Stored Procedure which is **CODE#2** and **CODE#3**.

**Expected Output of CODE#2 and CODE#3 :**

```
{

           |  classtype character varying |

           |   class-A          |

           |   class-B          |

           |   sports-A         |

           |   RED              |

           |   BLUE             |

           |    .......         |

}
```

**`What did i find Strange?`**

The **CODE#2** is returning the Expected Output some times and some times it returns "Unexpected output". What is the Reason behind ?

The **Code#3** is working fine and resulting the Expected Output Every Time.

Unexpected Output of CODE#2 :

{

```
       |  get_class_type_list character varying |

       |   class-A          |

       |   class-B          |

       |   sports-A        |

       |   RED                 |

       |   BLUE              |

       |    .......                |
```

}

**Following are the Code Snippets :**

**`CODE#1`**

```
 {

                  CREATE TABLE test.class_type
                 (
                     value character varying(80) NOT NULL,
                     is_active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
                    sort_order integer,
                    CONSTRAINT class_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (value)
                 )
                 WITH (
                  OIDS=FALSE
                );

}
```

**CODE#2**

```
 {
                  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.get_class_type_list()
                      RETURNS  SETOF character varying AS
                 $BODY$
                 DECLARE
                        SQL VARCHAR;
                    BEGIN
                         RETURN QUERY
                                (SELECT value AS "classType"
                                FROM TEST.CLASS_TYPE);
                   END;
              $BODY$
               LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
               COST 100
               ROWS 1000;

}
```

**CODE#3**

```
{
             CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.get_class_type_list()
                RETURNS TABLE(classType character varying) AS
            $BODY$
            DECLARE
                     SQL VARCHAR;
              BEGIN
                   RETURN QUERY
                     (SELECT value AS "classType"
                      FROM TEST.CLASS_TYPE);

              END;
                $BODY$
             LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
             COST 100
             ROWS 1000;

 }
```

**[SQL Fiddle Sample Code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/70e9a/1)**

**`Edited:`**

I want the column name of the Return Function to be as "classType", but not the function name.

Comment: What's the actual difference between the "expected" and "unexpected" results? (Your formatting is pretty hard to follow, why don't you show the actual output from `psql`?)

Comment: @CraigRinger I had added a SQLFiddle Sample Code

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @09Q71AO534 So you run two different queries and get the same result. Where's the problem here? Explain, using words, the difference between the output sets, what you think is wrong with the one you see as different, and how it is different.

Comment: The only difference I see in the results, is the column name (which is actually an alias). You have full control over column aliases at the calling context: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/73cc8/6 (and the reason, sometimes it behaves differently, it's because `RETURNS SETOF <primitive-type>` is a special returning clause)

Comment: @pozs Thanks for the Clarification, I want to know the Reason why it sometimes behaves differently? I just got to understand it by your comment. I check [this as well](http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/12/create-function-return-types.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just want to know y the column name sometimes displays as "classType" if i use RETURNS SETOF<<param>>?

Comment: @09Q71AO534 unfortunately, i didn't find any reference for this in the docs, but the rule of thumb is, if you have alias in the function definition (like `OUT` parameters, `RETURNS TABLE` & `RETURNS SETOF <composite/row-type>`; but not in the function body itself), postgresql will use that, unless there is an explicit alias. If you use `RETURNS SETOF <primitive/simple-type>` without `OUT` parameters, the default alias is the function name for that column.

Comment: @pozs The answer satisfied my need, please post it as a answer,so that to benefit others in reaching to correct answer easily.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I see in the results, is the column name (which is actually an alias). You have full control over column aliases at the calling context: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/73cc8/6) (and the reason, sometimes it behaves differently, it's because `RETURNS SETOF <primitive-type>` is a special returning clause).

The rule of thumb is, if you have alias in the function definition (like `OUT` parameters, `RETURNS TABLE` & `RETURNS SETOF <composite/row-type>`; but not in the function body itself), postgresql will use that, unless there is an explicit alias. If you use `RETURNS SETOF <primitive/simple-type>` without `OUT` parameters, the default alias is the function name for that column.

*Note*: the reason behind I didn't post this as an answer the first time, is because unfortunately, I couldn't find any reference for this in the docs.